# Как лучше перевести слово "sample"

Tags: переводы, английский-язык

Есть прибор спектрофотометр.
Результатом измерения является цветовая координата (measurement).
Measurements загружаются в программу по оценке цвета.
В программе любому measurement можно задать статус - reference, с которым будут сравниваться остальные measurements, которым в программе присваивается статус samples. В итоге имеем три английских слова: measurement (замер), reference (эталон). Проблема с переводом sample.
Прямой перевод - "образец" - очень близок по значению к слову "эталон" и создает путаницу.
Слово "проба" звучит коряво, так как подразумевает часть целого (проба воздуха...). В нашем случае замеры - это равноценные, самостоятельные единицы. Пожалуйста, помогите подобрать короткий вариант перевода sample!

Comment: Варианты перевода "по смыслу": тест, пробный образец, пробное испытание.

Comment: Я бы сказала «образчик» , который имеет точно такое же значение, но не имеет значения «эталон»

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за предложенные варианты!!! Вы правда очень помогли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по описанию прибора, вариант перевода reference - эталон не самый удачный. Возможны и другие: reference (point) - точка отсчета, ориентир, опорная точка.

Вместо варианта перевода sample - проба стоит рассмотреть sample – выборка, что вполне соответствует словосочетанию «брать / взять пробу».

А почему мы должны отказываться от перевода возможным словосочетанием? Например:
comparison of samples - сравнение выборок
sample measurements - выборочные измерения
sample readings - выборочные показания (прибора)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за обстоятельный ответ! Он мне очень полезен!

Comment: Пожалуй, даже приму Ваш ответ!